# I can't see why an "IF" won't work in my .BAT File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When the last command in this program:

```
If %V_EOM% EQU V_Day Set V_Type = M
```

Is executed, the the .BAT file run just goes away and the following pause is not executed.  I just don't see the problem.

```
Rem XCopy C: Britt* Folders to Backup
Rem *************************************

Rem Set EOM/Daily Switch
Set V_Type = D

Rem Set /d Switch
Set V_DSwitch = /d

Set V_Output_Drive = G:\
Set V_File_Name_1 = XCopy
Set V_File_Name_2 = Backup
Set V_File_Name_3 = Daily

Date /t
Time /t

set V_Date = %date:~0,20%
set V_DOW = %date:~0,3%
set V_Mo= %date:~4,2%
set V_Day = %date:~7,2%
set V_Yr= %date:~10,4%

Rem EOM Check
If %V_Mo%  EQU 04 GoTo Mo30:
If %V_Mo%  EQU 06 GoTo Mo30:
If %V_Mo%  EQU 09 GoTo Mo30:
If %V_Mo% EQU 11 GoTo Mo30:
If %V_Mo% EQU 02 GoTo Mo28:
GoTo Mo31:

:Mo28
Set V_EOM = 28
GoTo CkEOM:

:Mo30
Set V_EOM =30

:Mo31
Set V_EOM = 31
GoTo CkEOM:

Rem Check to see if today is the End of Month
:CkEOM
pause
If %V_EOM% EQU V_Day Set V_Type = M
pause
```

---

Revised code transferred from "answer"

```
set V_Date = %date:~0,20%
set V_DOW = %date:~0,3%
set V_Mo = %date:~4,2%
set V_Day = %date:~7,2%
set V_Yr = %date:~10,4%
Set V_Out_Date = %V_Yr %%V_Mo %%V_Day %
Set V_File_Name_1=XCopy.Backup
Set V_File_Name_2=Daily
Set V_File_Name_3= %V_Out_Date %
Set V_Dir=Britt Michael
```

Gives me: XCopy.Backup Daily 2015 02 06 Question: How do I make the output = XCopy.Backup.Daily 2015-02-06

Comment: V_EOM always is 31 at CkEOM.

Comment: Your fundamental issue is that Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAGSpace" to a value of "SpaceN". For that reason, @JasonFaulkner advised you to remove the spaces in your `set` statements, so `set V_Date = %date:~0,20%` should be `set V_Date=%date:~0,20%` or preferably `set "V_Date=%date:~0,20%"` for instance (the latter ensures trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned.) .  Your code, requiring the space in the varname is hard to read, write and maintain.

Comment: Please don't ask supplemental questions - it generates an endless series of revisions. It's free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

The line:

```
If %V_EOM% EQU V_Day Set V_Type = M
```

Should probably be:

```
If %V_EOM% EQU %V_Day% Set V_Type=M
```

---

In general though, your script syntax is off. For example:

```
Set V_File_Name_1 = XCopy
```

Will create the variable `%V_File_Name_1 %` (space on the end) which means `%V_File_Name_1%` would be undefined. Additionally the value would be `(space)XCopy` (space in front) and not just `XCopy`.

Since you are using the syntax:

```
Set Var = Value
```

with spaces between the `=`, your logic is likely to fail on comparisons.

Update them to use the syntax:

```
Set Var=Value
```

or

```
Set "Var=Value"
```

Comment: agree, looks like you need to take the space out between the variable and '=' sign. Also remove the space from between the '=' and what you are assigning as a value

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I had tried 'If %V_EOM% EQU %V_Day% Set V_Type=M' and it didn't work,  I tried again and it still doesn't work.  The problem should be so obvious, but I don't see it.  As far as the other helpful hints, I will try all them as soon as I get by the killer.  Any other help for the 'If' command?

Comment: @MichaelEdwardBritt - the problem is `%V_EOM%` and `%V_Day%` do not exist due to the issue noted above. They would be  `%V_EOM %` and `%V_Day %` (note the space in the variable name) instead. I would suggest fixing the variable name issue and then your problem will likely disappear.

Comment: @MichaelEdwardBritt - If this resolved your issue, please mark as the answer to close the question out. Cheers.

Comment: @MichaelEdwardBritt - You just click the checkbox next to the top of the answer (below the vote counter). Once you click it, it will turn green to indicate you marked it as the answer.